# Dynamically load views / templates in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I have a table and I want to show it in two different ways. Different number of columns and position of its content and cells. 
I would like to provide users with a way to change from one to another view by just clicking a button.

I started doing it by just using the `visible` binding, but then I realized it was not the proper way of doing it as the content was just `invisible` but it was still being loaded in the DOM. 
I was duplicating content in the background and generating invalid HTML (duplicate `id` attributes in both tables, for example) and that was generating problems in the jQuery side.

Then I took a look at [the use of knockout templates to accomplish it](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-dynamically-changing.html) as [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ujr4z/light/), and it solves my previous problems and it works, **but** using HTML inside `<script>` tags doesn't sound like the cleanest solution to me.

I'm not quite sure if the use [of components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) can provide any solution for this cases, I wasn't able to find one.

Any suggestions about how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `knockout components + AMD` is definitely what you're looking for. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1USsIW8aWE) by Steve Sanderson, the author of `knockout`. It explains how to architect a SPA using `ko` with `requirejs`. It should clear your doubts

Example:

```
...
<div data-bind="component: myDynamicComponent"> </div>
...
```

Then, if you have your [component loader](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html) configured to fetch its template & | or viewModel asynchronously you can have `myDynamicComponent` as an observable:

```
function RootViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.myDynamicComponent = ko.observable('some-component');

    this.someButtonClicked = function() { 
        self.myDynamicComponent('some-other-component'); // this should render your other component async (only if you configured your component loader to do so)
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess the way to emulate a dynamic template and load one or the another would be by using two components and setting the data to `null` or to the actual `data` depending on the one I want to show?

Comment: @Alvaro: I have edited my answer, I'll try to post a more complete example tonight

Comment: Thanks a lot for it @Daniel, I believe I managed to get the same result as [this template example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ujr4z/light/) in [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujr4z/655/) by using components as you said. Let me know if there's something I did wrong or that it can be improved.

Comment: @Alvaro: Your fiddle is fine, but note you are still not asynchronously loading your components. However, using components is still cleaner there than using the template binding

Comment: what do you mean regarding the asynchronous loading? The fact that I'm not using files for their templates?

Comment: @Alvaro: I mean fetching your templates (even your viewmodels) via ajax, or using AMD. Example 2 [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html) shows a way of doing it using jquery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Templates inside `script` tags are superseded by [template tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). You might look at [this recent answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860980/knockout-components-or-templates-performance-gains/31927273#31927273) for an example.

Update: Not all the Knockout component documentation has been updated, but it is [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#specifying-a-template).

Another option is [dynamically loading templates via AMD (require.js)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#an-amd-module-whose-value-describes-a-template).

Comment: It's not in all the component docs, but it is here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#specifying-a-template

Comment: It seems the `<template>` tag is [not supported in any IE version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template).

Comment: Good to know. Just another reason to avoid IE. :)

Comment: it doesn't sound like the best solution. IE 10 and 11 are widely used.

Comment: @Alvaro So is IE8, but I won't code for it. Sometimes you have to deal with undesirable things, but sometimes you don't.